# Cannot resolve method 'findNode' in 'Transaction'

Tags: java, neo4j, traversal

I'm trying to understand *Traversal API* for *Neo4j*, but I have a problem with dependencies:

```
Cannot resolve method 'findNode' in 'Transaction'
```

also:

```
Cannot resolve method 'traversalDescription' in 'Transaction'
```

Here is my code (because of the dependencies, I'm still not sure if it's working - any tips unrelated to the question will be appreciated):

```java
import org.neo4j.driver.Driver;
import org.neo4j.driver.AuthTokens;
import org.neo4j.driver.GraphDatabase;import org.neo4j.driver.Session;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.*;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "password"));
        try (Session session = driver.session()) {
            // Start a new transaction
            try (Transaction tx = (Transaction) session.beginTransaction()) {
                // Get the traversal description
                TraversalDescription traversal = tx.traversalDescription()
                        .depthFirst()
                        .uniqueness(Uniqueness.NODE_GLOBAL);
                Node startNode = tx.findNode(Label.label("Node"), "id", 0);
                // Traverse the graph
                Traverser traverser = traversal.traverse(startNode);
                for (Path path : traverser) {
                    Node node = path.endNode();
                    System.out.println("Node id: " + node.getProperty("id"));
                }
                tx.success();
            }
        } finally {
            driver.close();
        }
    }
}
```

and `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>Traversal</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ZBD</name>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-graphdb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I've tried to use examples from [*neo4j* repository on *GitHub*](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-documentation/tree/dev/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples), but the dependencies are still an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your libraries and code are pretty old for now.
Here is a Maven POM file with the new versions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>Traversal</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ZBD</name>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-graphdb-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And do not use Traversal Framework, it looks like it is recommended to use Cypher now.
And easier to find samples. Please, look here: https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/java-embedded/cypher-java/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Updating the libraries and *Java* version to 17 let me compile the project.

I'll remember your advice not to use *Traversal*, but in this case, I'm supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing 2 different things.

The `neo4j-java-driver` is used to communicate to a remote server and allows only to execute Cypher queries:

```java
var authToken = AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "password");
try (Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", authToken);
     Session session = driver.session()) {
    var result = session.run("CREATE (n)");
    var summary = result.consume();
    System.out.println(summary.counters().nodesCreated());
}
```

The traversal Java API is used **within** an instance, either through an extension or Neo4j embedded. You cannot mix the Java driver and the traversal API together.

```java
try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
    Node node; // find some node
    for (Path path : tx.traversalDescription()
        .depthFirst()
        .relationships(Rels.KNOWS)
        .uniqueness(Uniqueness.RELATIONSHIP_GLOBAL)
        .traverse(node)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Notice here that the transaction is starting from `db`, an injected instance of a `GraphDatabaseService`, not from a Java driver's `Session`.

Side notes:

- version 3.0.1 of `neo4j-graphdb-api` is very old. Neo4j 3.0.1 has reached end of life [a long time ago.](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/neo4j-supported-versions/)
- your compiler configuration targets Java 8, the shorthand properties to target Java 11 are ineffective here

Comment: How to define the `db`?

Comment: I've tried to use: `DatabaseManagementService managementService = new DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder( databaseDirectory ).build();
    GraphDatabaseService db = managementService.database( DEFAULT_DATABASE_NAME );`, but I cannot import [`DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder` and `configuration`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRgun.png).

Comment: I assume that `dataDirectory` is an absolute path to neo4j database?

Comment: DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder is for embedded database

Comment: @maciejwww are you developing a Neo4j plugin or are you using an embedded instance of Neo4j? This is not included in the initial question. Assuming you're using an embedded instance, you will need org.neo4j:neo4j as a dependency.

Comment: I'm not sure. I used *browser Neo4j*, created a database and run some queries. I wanted to repeat the queries with Traversal API.

Comment: In that case, I think you're better off not using the traversal API and use the Java driver with the Cypher query language (first example in my initial reply).

Comment: It was my exercise requirement to use Traversal :/

Comment: In that case, remove the java-driver entirely. Start an embedded instance https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/java-embedded/ and you'll be able to do what's shown in the second code snippet.

Comment: @fbiville Thank you for your effort. I hope I'll achieve something.

Comment: @fbiville I see you're a developer at *Neo4j*, so maybe you'll be interested - at the classes I'm taking, we had to compare *Neo4j* and *PostgreSQL* on the same task - searching for distinct nodes achievable in *k* steps from given node (they called it "degrees of neighbourhood"). We have used *Epinions social network* database. And here's a confusion (**potentially interesting stuff for you**)  everybody met (also our lecturer was very surprised) - *PostgreSQL* was waaay quicker than *Neo4j*, although *Neo4j* is a graph database management system.

Comment: @fbiville If you want to see the queries we've used (and maybe point out our mistakes), write to me at mack.dzikowski@gmail.com